# CÓDIGO PARA PROTEGER FORMULARIO PHP

Tags: php, php7, php5, phpmailer

Requiero por favor me digan, que código adicionales puedo utilizar para proteger un formulario con php. Tengo el siguiente código de Enviar.php.

Que le puedo agregar adicionalmente, para proteger contra hakeos y códigos maliciosos.

```
<?php
$remitente = $_POST['email'];
$destinatario = 'pycondominicana@gmail.com'; // en esta línea va el mail del destinatario.
$asunto = 'Mensaje'; // acá se puede modificar el asunto del mail
if (!$_POST){
?>
```

```
<?php
}else{

    $cuerpo = "Nombre y apellido: " . $_POST["nombre"] . "\r\n"; 
    $cuerpo .= "Email: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n";
    $cuerpo .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST["mensaje"] . "\r\n";
    //las líneas de arriba definen el contenido del mail. Las palabras que están dentro de $_POST[""] deben coincidir con el "name" de cada campo. 
    // Si se agrega un campo al formulario, hay que agregarlo acá.

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
    $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: php\n";
    $headers .= "From: \"".$_POST['nombre']." ".$_POST['apellido']."\" <".$remitente.">\n";

    mail($destinatario, $asunto, $cuerpo, $headers);

    include 'mensajeEnviado.html'; //se debe crear un html que confirma el envío
}
?>
```

Gracias Anticipadas, espero me puedan ayudar, soy principiante.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es dar mayor seguridad a la creación de un formulario, puedes implementar google recaptcha, creo que no hacen falta las explicaciones, no obstante, cabe recalcar que ayuda a prevenir ataques de bots. Aqui un link para implementarlo en php: http://jonsegador.com/2017/05/configurar-recaptcha-2-0-con-php/

Comment: Añade texto plano, entiendo que no debes mantener unas medidas de seguridad extraordinarias, más allá de la inyección de spam desde robots.

Comment: Saludos, Ya inserte el recaptcha, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me falta, que cuando el usuario le da click a enviar, el botón no ejecute ninguna acción sin que el repcaptcha se haya ejecutado y que cuando se le de click, si permita enviar el mensaje. Me faltaría ese código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo te recomendaría limpiar las variables POST antes de utilizarlas, en PHP puedes utilizar la función **mysqli_real_escape_string()** para eliminar los caracteres especiales y así prevenir las inyecciones SQL.

Espero haberte podido ayudar.

Comment: Pequeño detalle no esta almacenando los valores en una BD, por lo tanto no puede usar función alguna de mysqli, lo que esta haciendo es mandar un correo

Comment: Tienes razón, no me había fijado... disculpa.